# Inner Join, multiple records with same ID, unexpected empty result set

Tags: mysql, inner-join

The query below returns an empty resultset. Why? I am looking to retrieve the id of 50. The problem appears to be related to the multiple AND statements at the end of the query.

EDIT: However, I only want the SELECT to return the id if BOTH rows exist in view_layout_rows_columns, not one or the other.

```
Table: view_layout_rows

ID    owner    rows
___________________
50    1        2



Table: view_layout_rows_columns

ID    row    columns
___________________
50    1      5
50    2      5


SELECT vlr.id
FROM view_layout_rows vlr
INNER JOIN view_layout_rows_columns vlrc
ON vlr.id = vlrc.id 
WHERE vlr.rows = 2
AND (vlr.owner = 0 OR vlr.owner = 1)
AND (vlrc.row = 1 AND vlrc.columns = 5) 
AND (vlrc.row = 2 AND vlrc.columns = 5)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Same table structure... but no data *in* the tables?

Comment: Zohaib, the data is similar! I haven't tested the same data set. The real question is whether there is an error in my syntax. I will edit the question.

Comment: If there was an error in the syntax, the RDBMS would not return even an empty resultset, but an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND (vlrc.row = 1 AND vlrc.columns = 5) 
AND (vlrc.row = 2 AND vlrc.columns = 5)
```

So, isn't that a bit contradictory? `vlrc.row` cannot equate to both 1 and 2. You probably want

```
AND vlrc.row IN (1,2)
AND vlrc.columns = 5
```

Comment: How might you write this if the columns values were different, but every row was required? e.g. 
(vlrc.row = 1 AND vlrc.columns = 3)
(vlrc.row = 2 AND vlrc.columns = 5)
(vlrc.row = 3 AND vlrc.columns = 4)

Comment: @Lemmy: you just don't put a condition

Comment: I'm pretty clear on what not to do at this point ;) Still not sure on how to write the correct query though.

Comment: You can write : `vlrc.columns = CASE vlcr.row WHEN 1 THEN 3 WHEN 2 THEN 5 WHEN 3 THEN 4 ELSE NULL END`. The NULL part ensures it never matches if `vlcr.row` is not in the set `1,2,3`.

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to work partially. I think a count would also be required to check that all the rows have been returned, as partial results are also returned - ie. where one row matches but not all.

Answer (score 0):

It should always return an empty result set because of this condition

```
AND (vlrc.row = 1 AND vlrc.columns = 5) 
AND (vlrc.row = 2 AND vlrc.columns = 5)
```

the value of vlrc.row can either be 1 or 2 at one time. I guess you wanted to do something like this

```
AND ((vlrc.row = 1 AND vlrc.columns = 5) 
OR (vlrc.row = 2 AND vlrc.columns = 5))
```

Comment: It is a requirement that there is a record for each row in view_layout_rows_columns with the declared values. That's why I didn't use OR.

Comment: This OR is between the parenthesis of AND. One of the conditions must be met 1,5 or 2,5. One of this must be true for the result to be selected. Else, the way you are trtinh to select it will always return an empty set, because every condition in the where clause is evaluated on every row of the table and in your case vlrc.row can not be 1 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: Yes, but the requirement is that both conditions 1,5 and 2,5 are true.
I will edit the question again for clarity :)